# Application static property is null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, static

I instantiate a static property at the beginning of Activity's `onCreate()`, but some of my users get `NullpointerException` when I try to get it in MainActivity.

Comment: Can you share you code bit, so we can check the reason of occurrence.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, you code should be

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static String mValue;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    mValue = "my_value";
}
```

}

The value  `TestActivity.mValue` should be null util the `onCreate` executes.You can init the `mValue` like this

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static String mValue;
static {
    mValue = "my_value";
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

}
```